# Android Keeping BT socket alive thru various activities

Tags: java, android, sockets, android-studio, bluetooth

[Click here to download codes for the app](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B0AT63YryKWCWGZuc1psMlVNTWs)

I would like to create an activity that will make connection with my BT device , later I will exit from that activity and use btsocket in other activities to read and send data over the Socket input output stream . 
I am unable to keep it alive,

I do not want o frequently connect and disconnect the BT socket in each activity , connection to device shall be made once and remain active till the application is running , I am using android studio appreciate is somebody can help

code is attached

Comment: Anything that outlives an `Activity` instance and is not `Parcelable` or `Serializable` should be owned by a retained `Fragment` or a `Service`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [service](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html). Put all you code in a service class and start it from your MainActivity.

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MyService.class);
startService(myIntent);
```